# Problemas al utilizar una relacion ManytoMany en Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Quiero hacer un programa que me permita guardar un pedido y que coja el precio y el idproducto de otra tabla.
He depurado y sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice que no encuentra el objeto. He probado a crearlo manualmente y tampoco lo encuentra.
Además de ese error también nos sale el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso el codigo de la clase Pedido y Producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el codigo del boton GuardarPedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon tanto el código como los mensajes de error como texto. Las capturas de imagen no ayudan en este caso. Y además es más simple, porque sólo tienes que copiar y pegar. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenida, no se ve el texto en las imágenes, agrega el código como texto, por favor, te sugerimos también revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Te sugiero atender las indicaciones mencionadas arriba, por otro lado, leyendo el código mostrado, te recomiendo revisar las anotaciones `@JoinColumn` de las entidades `Producto` y `Pedido`, puedes indagar del tema [aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column).